# Why is ground shared between primary and secondary side in LT3750 circuit example

Tags: design, high-voltage, isolation, switching-regulator

LT3750 is a capacitor charger controller IC. The sample (typical application) circuit in its [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3750fa.pdf) shows an otherwise isolated secondary side sharing a ground with the primary side. A PCB layout suggestion for the same circuit later also shows that the ground is shared, so this is an intentional part of the design, not a mistake.

What's the purpose of sharing a ground like that? Wouldn't it negate the benefits of isolation and make the lower voltage primary side susceptible to destruction by the high voltage from the secondary side (if the positive rail of the secondary somehow gets close to the primary side or sparks)?

[image: LT3750 typical application circuit]

Comment: I understand that the transformer is primarily used to get 10x voltage on the secondary side here, but I'm confused why it's chosen not to keep the isolation that one gets for free.

Comment: I can't see any reason - I think its just shown like that for convenience. It will work isolated, it comes down to what you are using the 300V for? do you need it referenced to the same ground as the supply side or not?

Comment: Its an application note written to showcase the chip accentuating the positive and eliminating the negative .I would do something with a cheap off the shelf inductor if the real application didnot need to be isolated .Maybe that was the way they tested it or maybe the transformer had to be really tightly coupled to maintain reasonable efficiency and stop M1 blowing up .Such a tight transformer may not make HV clearances.

Comment: It is just an example circuit, no one says you can not use isolation if you want it, but drawing it that way communicates that the chip should be fine sharing it.

Comment: if you want to simulate the circuit most software requires that every node has a path to ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that is a just an example circuit.

LTSpice needs you to have ground path for each node, easiest way to do this is put the standard grounds on both sides.

To simulate isolated grounds, put a very large (1,000,000,000 ohms or so) resistor and a very small (1 pico farad) capacitor in parallel. This gives you an isolated ground as you would have in real life. The LT Test Fixtures don't bother with this to keep the diagram clearer, and to make the simulation output nice and clear.

Obviously you will then have to give a label to the isolated ground, and measuring the voltage relevant to the isolated ground will require putting an equation in the simulation output to make the voltage you're interested relevant to the ground you are interested in.